# How can I link account in a parent/child relation using address or phone number?

Tags: mysql, parent-child

I am trying to link accounts in a parent child relationship

I have accounts in the accounts table each account has its own id "primary number", "group_id", phone, contact, email, fax.

I need to select all the accounts that has parents.

Here is how I define parent: first the GROUP_ID must be the same and it meets at least one of the following criteria

1. if the address are the same
2. if the phone number are the same
3. if the fax is the same
4. if the email is the same
5. if the first 6 chars of the address are the same

I have created a Fiddle to explain what I am trying to do
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1974f/5

here is the code

```
CREATE TABLE accounts(
  id int(11),
  name varchar(255),
  Address1 varchar(255),
  phone varchar(10),
  fax varchar(10), 
  email varchar(255),
  contact varchar(255),
  group_id int(11)
  );
INSERT INTO accounts(id, name, Address1, phone, fax, email, contact, group_id)
VALUES
(1, 'Program 1', '123 Main S','7542116654','7456113354','test@test.com','Blah Blah',10),
(2, 'Program 2', '123 Main South','745123456','7024568984','none@test.com','James',10),
(3, 'Program 100', '4512 1st ave','754219648','7452155546','Jim@test.com','Jim',13),
(4, 'Program 55', '12645 West Industry Ave','7023665520','7981234568','mike@test.com','Mike',15),
(4, 'Program Trop', '465431 E Tropicana Ave','7023665520','7024564546','Jay@test.com','Jay',10);
```

this is my attempt to pull the data

```
SELECT b.id AS parent, a.* FROM accounts AS a
INNER JOIN(
  SELECT * FROM accounts
) AS b ON a.id= b.id
WHERE
a.address1 = b.address1
OR LEFT(a.Address1 , 6) = LEFT(b.Address1, 6)
OR (a.phone = b.phone AND LENGTH(b.phone) = 10)
OR (a.fax = b.phone AND LENGTH(b.fax) = 10)
OR (a.contact = b.contact AND LENGTH(b.contact) > 5 )
OR (a.email = b.email AND LENGTH(b.email) > 5 )
```

The final output should give me the same data in the account table but with a column for the parent id if any.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

A query that does exactly what you ask is:

```
SELECT
  a1.*, a2.id AS parent
FROM
  accounts a1
  LEFT JOIN accounts AS a2 ON a1.group_id = a2.group_id
    AND (
      a1.Address1 = a2.Address1
      OR a1.phone = a2.phone
      OR a1.fax = a2.fax
      OR a1.email = a2.email
      OR (
        CHAR_LENGTH(a1.Address1) >= 6
        AND CHAR_LENGTH(a2.Address1) >= 6
        AND LEFT(a1.Address1, 6) = LEFT(a2.Address1, 6)
      )
    )
```

However, note that your conditions mean that an account is always a parent of itself and that if an account A is a parent of account B then B is also a parent of account A.

You can prevent this by adding `AND a1.id <> a2.id` (if you only want to prevent accounts being their own parent) or `AND a1.id > a2.id` (if you want to prevent accounts being their own parent AND prevent the relation going both ways).

Comment: Thank for this code. In my example it seems that is working fine when i include the AND a1.id > a2.id   but when I appy the same code to the actual table with 22k records The records that are generated by the select statement seems to double. may be because there are multi records in share the same group_id number and it is joining them all together with the left join?

Comment: Also in the query you provided I can't set the parent to be the same. It currently select any id that is generated than the current is.

Comment: If you want a maximum of one parent per record and there are multiple records that match, you'll have to think of a way to select one. The one with the smallest id?